# Advanced grouping in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to group events by their days.
Prefact:

```
   Available days are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
   One event can not contain duplicates. e.g [1,1,2,3]
   Setup is Ruby 1.9.2 with Rails 3.2
```

An event is containing like 8-10 more attributes(unnecessary to include in example, but should be considered, these attributes should still be there after grouping.) In other words the event objects should not be altered only grouped as is.

Consider an array with objects:

```
events = [
  {
    :name => "event1",
    :days => [1,2,3,4,5]
  },
  {
    :name => "event2",
    :days => [1,4,5]
  },
  {
    :name => "event3",
    :days => [1]
  },
  {
    :name => "event4",
    :days => [2]
  },
  {
    :name => "event5",
    :days => [3]
  },
  {
    :name => "event6",
    :days => [4]
  },
  {
    :name => "event7",
    :days => [5]
  },
  {
    :name => "event8",
    :days => [1,2,3]
  },
  {
    :name => "event9",
    :days => [1,5]
  },
  {
    :name => "event10",
    :days => [1,2]
  },
  {
    :name => "event11",
    :days => [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
]
```

**To be grouped an event must have at least 3 days. And these days should be in numerically order.**

*Example(should be grouped): [1,2,3]*

*Example(should not be grouped): [1,4,5]*

**Events that's not suitable for grouping should be placed in each day they contain.**

*Example: [1,4,5] should be placed in 1,4 and 5.*

The desired result of events array above:

```
[
  {
    :heading => "1",
    :events => [
      {
        :name => "event3",
        :days => [1]
      },
      {
        :name => "event9",
        :days => [1,5]
      },
      {
        :name => "event10",
        :days => [1,2]
      },
      {
        :name => "event2",
        :days => [1,4,5]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    :heading => "2", 
    :events => [
      {
        :name => "event4",
        :days => [2]
      },
      {
        :name => "event10",
        :days => [1,2]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    :heading => "3",
    :events => [
      {
        :name => "event5",
        :days => [3]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    :heading => "4",
    :events => [
      {
        :name => "event6",
        :days => [4]
      },
      {
        :name => "event2",
        :days => [1,4,5]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    :heading => "5",
    :events => [
      {
        :name => "event7",
        :days => [5]
      },
      {
        :name => "event9",
        :days => [1,5]
      },
      {
        :name => "event2",
        :days => [1,4,5]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    :heading => "1-3",
    :events => [
      {
        :name => "event8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    :heading => "1.5",
    :events => [
      {
        :name => "event1"
      },
      {
        :name => "event11"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It is very advanced Ruby here. Maybe too advanced for me, everything I've tried ends up missing one part of the equation. But hey it's Ruby, it shouldn't be that hard?

EDIT: Updated example with clarification and corrected expected output

Comment: event8 has three consecutive days and yet it's split in the output?

Comment: According to your rules, shouldn't event8 be in a "1-3" group?

Comment: How about `1,3,4,5`? Would it have a separate `1`, then a group of `3-5`? Or would it not group anything? And is it possible to have days like `1,1,2,3` or `5,3,1`?

Comment: The result you are expecting is redundant. You should expect `{"1-5" => ["event1", "event11"], "1" => ["event3", "event8", ...` instead.

Comment: @tokland, @DigitalRoss yes you are right, event8 should be in a "1-3" group, my mistake. @Amadan, No, all days need to me in numerically order and they cannot contain duplicates `1,1,2,3`. @sawa, What do you mean?

Comment: Personally, I'd use objects with attributes rather than a big data structure. This can make the answer *much* simpler. Do you have the ability to change the way the input is created?

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'pp'
pp(events.inject(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |m, e|
  days = e[:days]
  event = { :name => e[:name] }
  if days.size >= 3 && days.last - days.first + 1 == days.size
    m["%d-%d" % [days.first, days.last]] << event
  else
    days.each { |d| m[d.to_s] << event }
  end
  m
end)
```

Comment: And it works! Is there a way to get the grouped events last? group `"1-3"` should be before `"1-5"` etc. Updated question to give you an example.

Comment: Sure, in 1.8 or 1.9 you can get the results as an Array instead of a Hash, and in 1.9 (where Hash objects preserve their creation order) you could convert the Array back to a Hash. Put the result in `r` and then do: `r.sort_by { |k, v| k[2].to_i * 10 + k.to_i }` ..and.. in 1.9 you can make an order-preserving Hash out of that with just `Hash[r.sort_by { ... }]`

Comment: `if days.size >= 3 && (days.min..days.max).each_cons(days.size).detect{ |f| f == (days.min..days.max).to_a }`

Comment: Thank you @DigitalRoss it works! I have updated my question to reflect the implementation I'm looking for. I thought that I could figure the rest out by my self but was not able to. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify DigitalRoss's answer slightly.  I would change

```
    if days.size >= 3 && days.last - days.first + 1 == days.size
```

to

```
    if days.size >= 3 && (days.first..days.last).to_a == days
```

This will catch [1,1,3,4]...

It would also be wise to sort the days array before testing!